# Are Windows Services Restricted from Reading from %WINDIR% (C:\Windows)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I've got an application running as a Windows service that wants to read a file specified by a relative path. Since the service [is running under *C:\Windows\system32*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in) (on Server 2003 and Windows 7), I figure it should be reading the file from there. However, the file read always fails.

I put together some simple test code to try to open a file for reading, using an absolute path. While the service succeeds for files such as *C:\Temp\foo.txt*, it always fails for files like *C:\Windows\foo.txt* and *C:\Windows\system32\foo.txt* . `GetLastError()` returns `2`.

Am I running into an access issue? I couldn't find authoritative documentation on this. Is there any workaround?

Update:

The file test code is generic and straightforward:

```
std::ofstream out;
//...

std::string fileName("C:\\Windows\\system32\\Foo.txt");

hFile = CreateFile(fileName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  out << "Could not create file handle! (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
}
else {
  out << "Successfully opened file!" << std::endl;
  CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Comment: @Haw-Bin: paste relevant parts of the failing code. 2 means that something with the path is wrong (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`: file not found).

Comment: Wow! Just stumbled upon Microsoft's article on "File System Redirection", which may explain this for Windows 7 at least! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Haw-Bin: no it doesn't. A service process would not be subject to FS virtualization under normal circumstances.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: The article mentions running a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows, which is the case for my Windows 7 experience. Just now, I copied the file under *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*, and the file was found! This does not explain the situation for Server 2003, however, which is 32-bit.

Comment: @Haw-Bin: the virtualization feature and WOW64 file system redirection are still two different things. And you didn't mention anything about 64bit either ;) ... check out `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` then

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Thanks, I didn't mention it because I didn't realize at the time that it was a factor.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Error code 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` so it's likelier that the path you give simply does not exist or the file does not exist in that path. Without the relevant flags from `CreateFile` it's hard to give you a better answer.

But generally - under default conditions - a service would be allowed to read in that folder.

One more thing came to mind. How do you obtain the path (`C:\Windows` in your case)? The proper means are to use the API (e.g. `GetWindowsDirectory`) for this and not hardcode it.

Comment: Thanks - I'm hard-coding it for my test only, because I checked the value of `%WINDIR%` on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the windows service from Local System account. By default the service may be running from "Network Service" account.
To change the settings, Open Windows Service Manager (Run-> services.msc) and double-click your service. On property window select 2nd Tab "Log On" and change it to run with Local System account.

Comment: It is running under "Local System account" in both environments, with "Allow service to interact with desktop" unchecked.