# Windows filewatcher service crash on Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows-services, report-viewer2010

I have make a filewatcher service that reads every XML files put in a directory and print the content on labels (Visual Studio 2012,Report viewer 2010). Service works fine on Windows 8, but on server 2008 R2 I get a crash every time I copy a file in the directory.

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    public MyService ()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        GetSourcePath();
    }

    private void GetSourcePath()
    {
        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Company\\MyService", false);
        if (myKey == null)
        {
            fsw.Path = @"C:\Source\";
        }
        else
        {
            fsw.Path = (string)myKey.GetValue("SourcePath");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }


    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        base.OnContinue();
        GetSourcePath();
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();

        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"rptLabel.rdlc";
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet", PrintLabel.GetPrintLabels(e.FullPath)));
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();

        AutoPrint.Export(reportViewer.LocalReport);
        AutoPrint.Print();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }

}
```

And here the code for the other class

```
 public class AutoPrint
{
    private static int m_currentPageIndex;
    private static IList<Stream> m_streams;

    public static Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }


    public static void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>10cm</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>4cm</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();

        try
        {
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("My Service", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Error rendering print : " + exc.Message);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

        if(printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsDefaultPrinter) printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer Name";

        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0) System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Error: no stream to print.");

        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    public static void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {

        try
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Error rendering print page: " + exc.Message + "Inner exception :" + exc.InnerException );
        }

    }

}
```

There is also a static class printLabel for the datas, but nothing interesting for this case. It only loads datas. 
Here is the first error message from the log Event

Application: MyService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at MyService.MyService.fsw_Created(System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

Here the second message from the event log

Faulting application name: MyService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x51349c1b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17932, time stamp: 0x50327672
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x2dc4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce18d947393653
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\MyService\MyService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a27c24e2-84cc-11e2-bb34-0019992623e2

I made the same application as a console, it works perfectly.Maybe the service don't have the rights to read the files ? I someone has an idea ...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `FileNotFoundException` and you're using relative paths. That means the most likely problem is that you have wrong working directory. Try using absolute paths instead.

For some more information, see [What directory does a Windows Service run in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/884963/41071)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. it's the reportviewer 2010. After installing the ReportViewer Service Pack 1 it seems that he don't crash anymore. The crash occurs with the line :

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
```

I have also changed this line :

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyService.rptLabel.rdlc";
```