# Windows Service cannot locate Data Provider

Tags: .net, windows-services, oracle11g, .net-4.5, odac

I have a windows service which uses the Entity Framework in combination with [ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html).  The service simply polls a table within a database to check for records ready for processing.

The service works as expected on my development PC but not when deployed to the server.
The server has the same ODAC components installed and a console application which executes the same code works on both development PC and the server.

The error message I receive from the server for the windows service is as follows:

`System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)`

Googling this error message states that there is something not installed / configured properly with regards to the Data Provider, but then the console application works fine, so im not convinced this is the cause of the problem.

Any ideas are welcome and if more info is required, please ask.

Comment: Hello, only thing I can think of is the running directory of the application causing some "Lookup" issue. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in
Are you referring to any relative path in your application?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the console app running the same code is being executed from the same directory as the service and that works OK.  I suspect my problem is being caused by a permissions issue but regardless of what credentials I use for the service, I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this was something to do with the version of ODP.NET I was using.
32bit & 64bit versions weren't installed correctly and everything seems to work fine now i have re installed.