# log4net not logging when using external config file

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have found other posts with similar problems, but thus far I haven't been able to solve my particular case.

If I put the log4net configuration in the app.config then all works fine, but I want it in a separate file.

I have looked at the following links, and have tried to implement some of the proposed solutions (but perhaps I didn't understand it correctly):

[Similar SO question, but with web scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445976/log4net-config-in-external-file-does-not-work)

[Apache documentation, 'Reading Files Directly' section](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes)

[Tim Corey's log4net tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)

So here is my Log4NetSettings.config file's content (wrapped in a configuration element):

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO [Calculation Engine Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>


<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
</root>
</log4net>
```

I change the connectionstring value during runtime.

Here is what I have in the app.config:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="log4net"  type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
 <add key="log4net.Config" value="Log4NetSettings.config" />
</appSettings>
<log4net configSource="Log4NetSettings.config" />
```

In the executable class I have this:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4NetSettings.config", Watch = true)]
```

and then as soon as I can get hold of the connectionstring and configure it to the AdoNetAppender, I call:

```
 log.Info("Testing");
```

I also have:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

in the class with the assembly attribute and first logging call.

The Log4NetSettings.config file has its Build Action set to Content and its 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy Always'.

I have been pulling my hair out, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Should I have Log4NetSettings.config as just a normal xml file? 
Should I put the assembly attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file?
Should I rather call:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log4NetSettings.config"));
```

than have the assembly attribute?

It feels like I've tried so many different things, that perhaps I have mixed them up and gotten the wrong combination.

Comment: Did you try something like:    `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Config\LogConfig.xml"));`

Comment: I have tried something similar to your suggestion, but it seems it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have the log4net config in an XML file. When you have log4net in a separate file, it's no longer related to the app.config so the configuration section is not required, and the config should not be wrapped in a configuration element. (It isn't necessary to have the assembly attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs, and I note you have initialised the logging system in your startup code, which is [required when using the assembly attribute technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492817/43846))

Thus your log4net file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>  
    <!-- config .. -->
```

If you still have problems, log4net has diagnostic and debugging capability, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems) for how to enable it.

(Also, if you're using log4net 1.2.11 or later, you can [set the connection string name in the log4net config](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ConnectionStringName.html), assuming it is in your app.config)

Comment: I removed the wrapping configuration element from the Log4NetSettings.xml file (but left the log4net element like your suggestion above). I also removed the complete configSections and appSettings elements in the app.config file. I left the assembly attribute before the Main method in the executable class. It works! :-D Great joy and jubilation. I enabled the debugging as Ryan suggested, and saw that log4net couldn't connect to the db as expected without a connectionstring. I do not get my connectionstrings from the app.config but the connectionstringName would have been useful in such a case

Comment: log4net does complain mildly if the connection string isn't set when configured, but it will work OK if you set it manually afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `debug = "true"` to the `<log4net>` tag (i.e. `<log4net debug="true">` ) gives a lot of helpful information which may help to resolve.