# SC start service in folder /Start in:/

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, directory

I am solving one problem. I am trying to create a service for a program, but the .exe file has to be run in specific folder /File Properties - Start in/.
Is there any way how to add ,,Start in,, to service? All services runs from `C:\Windows\System32`.. and this one I want to run from `C:\WinACD`

```
sc create WinACD binpath= "C:\WinACD\WTELS.EXE Z" start= auto
```

I have to change working directory: `C:\WinACD`

Thank you all,
Robert

Answer (score 2):

In the end I downloaded a program, which works perfectly for my case.

http://nssm.cc/