# How to get absolute file path from an Windows Service in Python?

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

I have an windows service made in Python. This is working fine. But I need get the file path where my service are **installed**. I have tried to use these codes bellow:

```
os.get getcwd()
```

**Returns:**

> Windows System32 folder

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

**Returns:**

> NameError: global name '**file**' is not defined

How can I get the file path to my windows service application?

Comment: To access the absolute path use os.path.abspath()
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Comment: What do you get if you `print sys.prefix` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What directory does a Windows Service run in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in)

Comment: Thanks @MartinEvans! This tip works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sys.prefix` to obtain the folder used for the `EXE`. 
This holds the EXE's folder when a utility such as `py2exe` has been used to create it.

`sys.path` for example will hold the path to `python24.zip`