# Change "Start in" path of Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, window, regedit

Windows services, by default, run in `%WinDir%\System32`  (From this answer: [What directory does a Windows Service run in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in) ).

I would like this to be run in `C:\Path\To\Django\` instead, and can't change the python code.

I am assuming it will be a `regedit` key:value, but not sure what it is.

I currently have:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<My Service>\Parameters`

the key:value pair

`Application: "C:\ProgramData\python.exe" "C:\Path\To\Django\manage.py" runserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `AppDirectory` string value to the Parameters Key and set the value to your desired working directory.

`AppDirectory: "C:\Path\To\Django"`

Credit to Mark on: https://serverfault.com/questions/114238/windows-service-can-i-configure-the-current-working-directory