# Topshelf service can't find dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, topshelf

I have an unmanaged dll that I import into my c# console application:

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll", EntryPoint = "myfunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void MyFunction();
```

The application works just fine.

Then, I use Topshelf to host my console app as a service:

```
 var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<StartupService>();
            x.RunAsLocalSystem()
             .StartAutomatically()
             .EnableServiceRecovery(r =>
             {
                 r.RestartService(0);
                 r.SetResetPeriod(1);
             });

            x.SetStartTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
            x.SetStopTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
            x.SetDescription("my service");
            x.SetDisplayName("service");
            x.SetServiceName("service");
        });
```

I install and start the service like so:

```
myapp.exe install
myapp.exe start
```

The service starts, but an error appear in logs saying it can't find my dll:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'mylib.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

- The dll resides in the same directory as the application executable
- I added mylib.dll's dependencies into PATH. (i also tried copying them into app directory with no luck).
- The application works just fine when I run it .exe
- There are a bunch of other dlls I added and the service has no problem finding those

**Update:**
 I tried passing a full path and even putting it into System32. Still does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a full path to that native dll or try to set current dir to the location of exe, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in

Comment: Yes, I tried passing a full path and even putting it into System32. Still does not work.

Comment: Ok, then I would check that service process has the same bittness (in task manager -> select columns -> platform, 32- or 64-bit) than the dll. If they have same bittness, I would check with procmon how the service is trying to find the dll.

Comment: Fixed. The service could not find one of the dlls my lib depends on. Even though I added a path to it into PATH.. procmon tool was really helpful. Thanks a lot!