# What configuration do I need to get a Windows Service project to read and write from a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, service, entity-framework-core

I previously had a working console application project that will read and write settings to a local SQLite database file.

Based on this project, I converted it to a windows service project by porting over the classes and use the ServiceBase class to create the the service.
However, each time I run the service, I keep getting an `SqliteException` with the Message `SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Settings'.`

Using `DB Browser for SQLite`, I do see the table present in the database file so I am not sure what is going on.

I have tried testing with my own account using Windows Service, I have tried giving Local System access to my build folder for testing.

I am not sure if this helps but I have also included part of the DbContext file:

```
public class CDIContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=ApplicationData.db");
    }
}

public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 LastUpdateEpochUTC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use a full path to your database file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the Windows Service Working directory is located in either:
`C:\Windows\System32` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and not my application directory

[What directory does a Windows Service run in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in)

As such, my database files were being searched in those directories instead of the application directory.

Will take @ErikEJ advice and change to a full path.